# Spring boot: JSP not found (404)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot, web

I'm trying to create a new project with spring boot.
But I'm getting Error described below. I have added my code.

**Error**

> HTTP ERROR 404 page not found

Here is the link of my project structure.

[image]

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.wc</groupId>
    <artifactId>wc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>wc</name>
    <description>Work configurator project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>`
```

**login.jsp** contains just `hello`

**LoginController.class**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
@RequestMapping(value = {"/","/login"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getLoginPage(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("login");
    return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**WcApplication.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WcApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WcApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Why I'm getting this and how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Have you added any `ViewResolver`?

Comment: @gohil90  got thit at application.properties : 
'spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/ spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp'

sry, forgot about this in question

Comment: try to open up the logs with debug threshold, because i think you might need another dependency , as there is a problem with the embedded-tomcat jar, and he does not compile the jsp at runtime , thus need to add another one , check [mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/)

Comment: @Ivan: did you get it working? if yes, do you mind to update what fixed it?

Comment: @Ivan you can add the missing part in the question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48439452/edit) it. Also, please add the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and it took me long time to figure out that there are three conditions.

1.) In application properties you need to have the following view resolver mapping
(You can use java based as well):

```
logging.level.web=DEBUG
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/pages/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

Note: you have to create "WEB-INF" folder by yourself as in my case "webapp" 
   folder was empty. DEBUG property is not necessary just keep it as it will 
   help you find the root cause from logs.
```

2.) I had to make the packaging as "war" instead of jar.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

3.) Make sure you have added tomcat jasper dependency to compile the jsp pages at
runtime.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Hope it helps and feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed out `ViewResolver` configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

Try above configuration and it should call `login.jsp` page.

---

### Update

As you have correctly added resolver in `application.properties`. I figured that the problem is with folder `WEB-INF`. This folder is secured from outer access and `.jsp` files should not be inside of this folder. It is for files like `web.xml` which should not be exposed to client.

Just rename it to `view` (or something else) and change `application.properties` as -

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/view/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

This should definitely work.

Comment: i got thit at application.properties : 
'spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp'

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had everything correctly setup in spring boot. The `jsps` were in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`
and `index.html` the welcome page in `src/main/resources/static/index.html`. Still howevere hard I tried the jsp pages were not getting rendered. I always got `404` return.

But when I changed the build process to create a war field instead of the jar file it worked fine.

Just made additional line change in the `build.gradle` file as below

```
apply plugin: "war"
```

and after that while ruuing the war as java `-jar demo.war` everything fell in place and started working.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue occur. Project structure was correct and everything looked good. I made a slight change to my application.properties spring.mvc.view.prefix. I changed "/WEB-INF/jsp/" to "WEB-INF/jsp/" and everything works correctly. I think in the generate target and war it is the root directory so the additional / as a prefix was confusing something

Answer (score 0):

Its a hierarchy problem, the WEB-INF should be under webapp folder.

```
yourMainPackage/src/main/webapp/WEB_INF
```

(note that for it to work with springboot default configuration, webapp/ should be under main/ and not under resources)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/web.html#web.servlet.embedded-container.jsp-limitations there are some caveats when using JSPs with embedded containers in an executable archive:

- you must use `.war` packaging (as per the other answers)
- only Tomcat and Jetty support this (no Undertow)
- do not execute the .war directly, instead launch with `java -jar`
- custom `error.jsp` might not work as expected

and another thing I found out the hard way:

- DO NOT rename the `.war` to `.jar` when copying it into your docker image :)