# How can I fix duplicated folders in the path while accessing the page?

Tags: java

I have the *technical* question related to the issue as:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Jan 12 13:49:28 CET 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
JSP file [/admin/project_category/admin/project_category/list.jsp] not found
```

with accessing the page `http://localhost:8080/admin/project_category/list`.

While debugging *controller*:

```
@GetMapping("admin/project_category/list")
public ModelAndView projectCategoryList() { 
  List<Project> projectList = projectServiceImpl.get(); 
  ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("admin/project_category/list"); 
  modelAndView.addObject("projectList", projectList); 
  return modelAndView; 
}
```

inside the [project](https://github.com/invzbl3/RestApiApplication/blob/main/src/main/java/com/test/application/web/AdminController.java#L72), I don't have any duplicated folders:

[image]

but using the browser will be another situation:

[image]

There's I see I need [additional resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439452/spring-boot-jsp-not-found-404/48440018#48440018), but in the following project I don't need to use any [specific resolvers](https://github.com/anantjain6/ProductManagementSystem/blob/master/src/main/java/me/anant/PMS/controller/ProductCategoryController.java#L56).

I don't quite understand, why I don't have it twice in [similar project](https://github.com/anantjain6/ProductManagementSystem/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties#L2).

Can someone tell me, please, what do I need to fix to handle this problem finally? Is it the problem with `JSP` files specifically or something?

Thank you in advance for any helpful ideas.

**UPD:**

After some observation, I see:

if I have the following snippet of code:

```
@GetMapping("admin/project_category/list")
public ModelAndView projectCategoryList() {
    List<Project> projectList = projectServiceImpl.get();
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("admin/project_category/list");
    modelAndView.addObject("projectList", projectList);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

I'm getting the issue as:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu Jan 12 13:49:28 CET 2023 There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). JSP file [/admin/project_category/admin/project_category/list.jsp] not found
```

If I add slash in the beginning as:

```
@GetMapping("/admin/project_category/list")
public ModelAndView projectCategoryList() {
    List<Project> projectList = projectServiceImpl.get();
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/admin/project_category/list");
    modelAndView.addObject("projectList", projectList);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

I'm getting another issue as:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Cannot invoke "java.util.List.iterator()" because "projectCategory" is null java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.iterator()" because "projectCategory" is null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To fix the issue:

> Fri Jan 13 23:16:50 CET 2023 There was an unexpected error
> (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Cannot invoke
> "java.util.List.iterator()" because "projectCategory" is null
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "java.util.List.iterator()" because "projectCategory" is null

I needed to change the parameter `projectCategory` instead of `projectList`:

```
@GetMapping("/admin/project_category/list")
public ModelAndView projectCategoryList() { 
   List<Project> projectList = projectServiceImpl.get();    
   ModelAndView modelAndView = 
   new ModelAndView("/admin/project_category/list"); 
   modelAndView.addObject("projectList", projectList);
   return modelAndView; 
}
```

as the following:

```
@GetMapping("/admin/project_category/list")
public ModelAndView projectCategoryList() { 
   List<Project> projectList = projectServiceImpl.get(); 
   ModelAndView modelAndView = new 
   ModelAndView("/admin/project_category/list"); 
   modelAndView.addObject("projectCategory", projectList); 
   return modelAndView; 
}
```

2. To fix the issue with *duplicated folders* in the path:

> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a
> fallback.
> Sat Jan 14 00:01:17 CET 2023 There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found,
> status=404). JSP file [/admin/project_category/admin/project_category/list.jsp]
> not found

you need to add slash in the beginning of mapping declaration:

```
@GetMapping("admin/project_category/list")
public ModelAndView projectCategoryList() { 
List<Project> projectList = projectServiceImpl.get(); 
   ModelAndView modelAndView = new 
   ModelAndView("admin/project_category/list"); 
   modelAndView.addObject("projectCategory", projectList); 
   return modelAndView;
}
```

as the following:

```
@GetMapping("/admin/project_category/list")
public ModelAndView projectCategoryList() {
    List<Project> projectList = projectServiceImpl.get();
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new 
    ModelAndView("/admin/project_category/list");
    modelAndView.addObject("projectCategory", projectList);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

3. To fix the issue:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
> /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. Sat Jan 14 00:22:21 CET
> 2023 There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
> status=500). class com.test.application.data.models.Project cannot be
> cast to class com.test.application.data.models.ProjectCategory
> (com.test.application.data.models.Project and
> com.test.application.data.models.ProjectCategory are in unnamed module
> of loader
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader
> u/6ef9aa30) java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> com.test.application.data.models.Project cannot be cast to class
> com.test.application.data.models.ProjectCategory
> (com.test.application.data.models.Project and
> com.test.application.data.models.ProjectCategory are in unnamed module
> of loader
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader
> u/6ef9aa30)

I needed to change to the correct type inside [list.jsp](https://github.com/invzbl3/RestApiApplication/blob/027a825ae6a0905cd583227472149042215c5c55/src/main/webapp/project_category/list.jsp#L28):

```
<tbody>
            <%
                List<ProjectCategory> projectCategory = (List<ProjectCategory>) request.getAttribute("projectCategory");
                for (ProjectCategory c : projectCategory)
                {
            %>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><%=c.getId()%></th>
                <td><%=c.getName()%></td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="update?id=<%=c.getId()%>" role="button">Edit</a>
                    <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it?');" class="btn btn-danger" href="delete?id=<%= c.getId() %>" role="button">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%
                }
            %>
</tbody>
```

to another type of `List` as:

```
<tbody>
            <%
                List<Project> projectCategory = (List<Project>) request.getAttribute("projectCategory");
                for (Project c : projectCategory)
                {
            %>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><%=c.getId()%></th>
                <td><%=c.getName()%></td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="update?id=<%=c.getId()%>" role="button">Edit</a>
                    <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it?');" class="btn btn-danger" href="delete?id=<%= c.getId() %>" role="button">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%
                }
            %>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
@GetMapping("admin/project_category/list")
public ModelAndView projectCategoryList(Map<String, Object> model) { 
  List<Project> projectList = projectServiceImpl.get(); 
  //ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("admin/project_category/list"); 
  //modelAndView.addObject("projectList", projectList); 
  model.put("projectList", projectList);
  //return modelAndView; 
  return new ModelAndView("list");
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for sharing. I think it's partly helpful. I'll update your answer, if I find the way how to fix intermediate issue after using this snippet.

Comment: My Code is used in Spring Boot + JSP + Servlet. (need add some config in application.properties) . Maybe next time provide mode specific information like Tomcat version , jdk version , config, import package ....)